# Printf() - printed characters limit

Tags: c++, c, printf

I am trying to find what is the allowed limit for the number of characters to be printed by `printf()` in the C standard. I only found the [answer](http://computer-programming-forum.com/17-c-language/e00e14bab71d1c52.htm) in a discussion forum, which indicates `INT_MAX`.

For example, I checked the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// INT_MAX  2147483647

int main()
{
    int x=3;

    int y = printf("%2147483647d \n\n", x); --> Confirms INT_MAX ?

    // If I change the above to 2147483648, y in set to -1
    printf("y = %d\n\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to ask why is `printf()` limited by `INT_MAX` ? Can anyone point out a C standard reasoning or source code reference ?

**Edit**

The closest answer I found was for `fprintf()`. At this [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), on page 568, its mentioned (under undefined behavior):

```
The number of characters or wide characters transmitted by a formatted output
function (or written to an array, or that would have been written to an array) is 
greater than INT_MAX.
```

Will the above justify for `printf()` as well ?

Comment: That `printf()` is limited by `INT_MAX` is not surprising. When in doubt, it's limited by `INT_MAX`.

Comment: But what is the reason ?

Comment: It obviously uses `int` for storing amount of characters printed. You cannot store value larger than `INT_MAX` in `int`.

Comment: The specification says "a decimal integer". It would be reasonable to assume it means `int`

Comment: `%*d` _As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In
this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision._ but `printf("%*d", INT_MAX, 1);` in my system abort :D.

Comment: *"Will the above justify for printf() as well ?"* Yes, per 7.21.6.3/2 *"The printf function is equivalent to fprintf with the argument stdout interposed before the arguments to printf."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you print with the format specifier %d, which indicates a integer number, of course your maximum printable number would be INT_MAX. But your example is wrong. You are trying to tell it to print INT_MAX digits on a number, but that, of course, far exceeds the actual numerical value INT_MAX.

As to why your example fails, I suppose printf() stores the amount of digits to print in an integer number itself.

Comment: Well the number to be printed is 3. I tried it with `%2d`, the output is `<space>3`. So its printing spaces (1 less than the number I specified) and then the 3. Is it still wrong ?

Comment: Well its wrong in the sense that you will never be able to print a number with INT_MAX digits with it, so specifying that many spaces is just gonna have the effect of having a bunch of spaces you don't need.

Comment: I can't find anything specific in the C standard regarding this right now, but I'd heavily wager that the implementation of it just stores the amount of digits to be printed in a integer variable. That is the most reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 3):

`printf` is stated to return number of characters printed or -1 in case or an error. Its return type is `int`. Maximum number you can store is `int` is `INT_MAX`.

What happens if you try to print more characters? Then `printf` cannot fulfill its contract: to return number of characters written. Standard does not says what to do when contract is impossible to fulfill, so the behavior in this case is undefined by not being defined in standard.

Answer (score 0):

"Printf just prints the result".

In other words, the number of characters that printf can print depends on the format specifier specified.

The standard syntax for printf is,

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

here based on "format", the character count limit is set.

from you snippet:

```
int y = printf("%2147483647d \n\n", x);
```

because, the value specified is well with the range.

Likewise, when you changed the value to `2147483648` it goes beyond range.

Answer (score 0):

This should have been a comment  but due to space restrictions, I had to submit this as an answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct ec
{
    char *c;
};

int main(void)
{
    printf("INTMAX : %d\n",INT_MAX);

    struct ec obj;
    size_t max=(size_t)INT_MAX+1000;
    size_t i;
    obj.c=malloc(max*sizeof(char));
    if(obj.c==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't allocate such big memory chunk\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(i=0;i<(max-1);i++)
        obj.c[i]='0';
    obj.c[i]='\0';
    printf(obj.c); // This appear to  print fine

    /* Not bothered to put a free(obj.c) here*/
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the problem is more with how `int` return type of the printf function. The return value is the number of characters printed and so it should be incremented per character print. I cannot think of what happens when printf prints (INT_MAX+1)nth character

**Note:** I neglected the compiler warnings.